# Three.js shadow artifacts on connecting planes

Tags: three.js

I get ugly shadow artifacts on my 3D model of a furniture module. They appear where two planes are connected. In these places there should be no shadows at all.

[Screenshot with shadow artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYMCE.png)

I played around with **shadow.bias**, but without a nice result.

Is there anything else I can try to get rid of these shadows?

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  alpha: true,
  antialias: true
});
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
```

[My code on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GQqhnZP4MJDNlXqrdDEI?p=preview)

**Update 2018-04-18**

I updated my code on Plunker as WestLangley suggested. The only thing that seems to have an impact is the value for **bias**.

I'm not happy with the result, when I set **bias = -0.0018**. With a negative **bias** all the shadows aren't in the right place anymore.

I don't think the problem is self-shadowing. The shadows are casted by the nearby objects and not by itself.

[Example with simple cubes on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bjoern68/6us4gnem/30/)

[Screenshot with shadows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZabJF.png)

Probably I have to live with this issue and the only solution is a trade-off with **bias**.

Comment: You are seeing self-shadowing artifacts. Try bias of -0.0018. Update to the current three.js revision. Avoid double-sided materials.

Comment: @WestLangley I updated my question because of your comment

Comment: Your examples have hidden, interior, back-facing faces that are casting shadows. Try `material.shadowSide = THREE.FrontSide` -- maybe with `bias` set.

Comment: With `material.shadowSide = THREE.FrontSide` and `bias = -0.004` I get a nice result. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

With `side: THREE.FrontSide` and `shadowSide: THREE.FrontSide` on the **material** and `shadow.bias = -0.004` on the **light** I get a nice result.

[I updated my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GQqhnZP4MJDNlXqrdDEI?p=preview)